# Laravel csv file validation

Tags: fgetcsv, laravel-5.4

I am trying to populate my users db with username and password directly form a csv file. I am successfully able to populate the db and now I want to validate if the input file is a csv or not. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

p.s. I am new to laravel so don't mind being thorough

Answer (score 0):

You can use the laravel validation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

```
$uploaded_file = Input::file('file');
        $file          = ['file' => $uploaded_file];
        $validation    = ['file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:csv']; // update here
        $validator     = Validator::make($file, $validation);
        $upload_path   = 'uploads/leads';

        if(!$validator->fails()){
            if($uploaded_file->isValid()){
                // do what ever you want here
            }
        } else {
            session()->flash('error', 'Error ');
            return redirect('anypath')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
```